# Refresh Every 24 hours Google chrome background.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created an extension. It loads records from server when my extension is installed. I wrote code in background.js file. My question is "When background.js calls and How to write code to get data from server for every 24 hours.

Comment: How to create an alarm for every 24 hours. Can u please share the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use chrome.alarms for Google Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727734/how-to-use-chrome-alarms-for-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: Use the code from the duplicate and change `periodInMinutes` to `24 * 60`, the `delayInMinutes` may be not needed.