# check max write operation quota for chrome.storage.sync

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

`MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR` in `chrome.storage.sync` has value 1,800 ([ref](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)).  But I want to know how many operations have been done so far in a minute.

I can think of 2 ways either I can keep a count variable maintaining the no. of operations or I can catch the `chrome.runtime.lastError` and perform the follow-up operation.
Is there any quick way to find out how many operations have been done so far?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of reading the internal number of performed/available operations.
It's not even exposed outside the underlying quota counter class in the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/browser/quota_service.h?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1472901497&l=122).

Do it manually: maintain a counter or check chrome.runtime.lastError, and postpone writing accordingly via [chrome.alarms API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) (or a simple setTimeout in case you're using a [persistent background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)).

Comment: didnt know about alarms API. How can I create one and call the method after 1 minute?

Comment: There are plenty of examples available (here's [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21644841/3959875)). And the documentation itself is simple enough.