# How to get Chrome Extension chrome.alarms firing consistently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm seeing some inconsistency with the chrome.alarms api for a chrome extension that I can't quite make sense of.

**Background**

I'm creating an alarm that is to fire every day at 9:30am, however it doesn't fire anywhere near 9:30am. When it does, it appears to be when I've 'woken' up the extension, either by interacting with the popup, or toggle enable/disable on the extension. I don't see any consistency, else I would be thinking it's a timezone issue of some sort.

I've verified that the alarms are indeed set, and set for the correct time. In the popup I'm doing a simple `chrome.alarms.getAll` and dumping out all the alarms & their times.

So everything seems to be set correctly and ready to go, but then they sadly don't fire even, 1 full day after the time they were set for.

**My Thoughts**

The only thing I can figure is the `background.js` is being [unloaded as it isn't "needed"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#lifetime). But in theory the [alarms Api should load background.js](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition) back up when they fire.

It's also possible I need to add `"background": { "persistent": false }` explicitly to my `background.js`? Or maybe I should bite the bullet and say `true`... but ideally it shouldn't be persistent I would think.

How do I get my alarms to be consistent and behave as I expect them, firing at 9:30am?

**Files**

background.js

```
// Create alarm when receiving an onMessage with 'createAlarm'
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.action == 'createAlarm') {
        chrome.alarms.create('MyAlarm', {
            when: moment().hour(9).minute(30).unix() * 1000
        });
    }
});

// onAlarm, create notification
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    chrome.notifications.create({
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'images/icon-128.png',
        title: 'Hello World!',
        message: 'I am a notification!'
    });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js",
            "scripts.es5/background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        ...
        "background",
        "notifications",
        "alarms"
    ]
}
```

Related: [How to use chrome.alarms for Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727734/how-to-use-chrome-alarms-for-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: I would try with persistent true to make sure that is not the issue

Comment: You set `when` to the today's 9:30 which may have already passed. Add `periodInMinutes` parameter set to 24h span. Also, make sure the browser option "Continue running background apps" is enabled.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm setting alarms for tomorrow's 9:30 as well. So I don't think that's the case, good thought though. I also think alarms set in the past fire immediately. (I've accidentally set some for the UNIX epoch and they fired right away. Heh)

Comment: Where do you define `moment()` and its methods?

Comment: You have clearly identified some possible directions for investigation: explicitly setting either `"background": { "persistent": false }` or `"background": { "persistent": true }`. Why have you not actually tried these?

Comment: @Makyen It's clipped out of the code sample. But it's just https://momentjs.com library which is imported as a background scripts. Makes working with dates / times simple and less error prone.